# Using a custom directing inside a ui-grid cell template

Tags: angularjs-directive

I am trying to use a custom directive `'validNumber'` inside a ui-grid cell template.

Here is my cell template

```
<div ng-if="!row.groupHeader" class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
  <div ng-if="row.entity.IsApplicable">
    <input ng-if="col.displayName == 'MetricValue'" type="--" ng-model="row.entity.MetricValue" validNumber>
    <input ng-if="col.displayName == 'Comments'" type="--" ng-model="row.entity.Comments">

  </div>
  <div ng-if="!row.entity.IsApplicable">
    <label>NA</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my controller with some dummy data

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate','ui.grid.edit','ui.grid.selection','ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.grouping' ]);

app.controller('SmartOfficeController', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', 'uiGridGroupingConstants', function ($scope, $http, $interval, uiGridGroupingConstants ) {



  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: false,
    enableColumnResizing: true,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,

    rowTemplate:'metricRowTemplate.html',
        enableColumnMenus: false,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'MetricName',displayName:'Metric Name',
        headerCellClass: 'white' ,
        grouping: { groupPriority: 0 }, 

        width: '35%', cellTemplate: '<div><div ng-if="!col.grouping || col.grouping.groupPriority === undefined || col.grouping.groupPriority === null || ( row.groupHeader && col.grouping.groupPriority === row.treeLevel )" class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="TOOLTIP">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div></div>' },
      { name: 'MetricGoalName', headerCellClass: 'white' , cellFilter: 'mapGender' },
      { name: 'SubMetricGoalName', headerCellClass: 'white' , },
      { name: 'MetricValue',displayName:'MetricValue', headerCellClass: 'white' ,cellTemplate: 'metricCellTemplate.html'},
      { name: 'Comments',displayName:'Comments', headerCellClass: 'white' ,  cellTemplate: 'metricCellTemplate.html'},
      {name:'Save', headerCellClass: 'white' ,cellTemplate:'metricSaveTemplate.html'}

    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    },
    isRowSelectable: function(row){
        return row.entity.IsApplicable;
      }
  };
  $scope.save=function(e,data){
    console.log("I have hit the save button");

  };

$scope.saveAll=function(){
  var selectedRows=$scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
    alert(selectedRows);
  alert("You clicked Save All button");
};

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
        var registeredDate = new Date( data[i].registered );
        data[i].state = data[i].address.state;
        data[i].gender = data[i].gender === 'male' ? 1: 2;
        data[i].balance = Number( data[i].balance.slice(1).replace(/,/,'') );
        data[i].registered = new Date( registeredDate.getFullYear(), registeredDate.getMonth(), 1 )
      }
      delete data[2].age;
      $scope.gridOptions.data =[{
    "MetricGoalDetailID": 1,
    "MetricID": 1,
    "MetricName": "Quality",
    "MetricGoalID": 1,
    "MetricGoalName": "Data accuracy of deliverables",
    "SubMetricGoalID": 1,
    "SubMetricGoalName": "SW Defect density: <= 0.4% of lines of code",
    "MetricValue":0,
    "Comments":"Dummy Comments1",
    "TrackingMonth":"",
    "IsApplicable":true
},

{
    "MetricGoalDetailID": 2,
    "MetricID": 1,
    "MetricName": "Quality",
    "MetricGoalID": 1,
    "MetricGoalName": "Data accuracy of deliverables",
    "SubMetricGoalID": 2,
    "SubMetricGoalName": "Reporting: >= 99.5%",
    "MetricValue":0.5,
    "Comments":"Dummy Comments2",
    "TrackingMonth":"",
    "IsApplicable":false
},

{
    "MetricGoalDetailID": 3,
    "MetricID": 1,
    "MetricName": "Quality",
    "MetricGoalID": 1,
    "MetricGoalName": "Data accuracy of deliverables",
    "SubMetricGoalID": 3,
    "SubMetricGoalName": "Data Management:  >= 99.5%",
    "MetricValue":12.4,
  "Comments":"Dummy Comments3",
    "TrackingMonth":"",
    "IsApplicable":false
},

{
    "MetricGoalDetailID": 4,
    "MetricID": 2,
    "MetricName": "Cost",
    "MetricGoalID": 1,
    "MetricGoalName": "MIB / CAPG support (Early Engagement, Cost Analysis, App Dev)",
    "SubMetricGoalID": 4,
    "SubMetricGoalName": "$25M",
    "MetricValue":4.5,
    "Comments":"Dummy Comments4",
    "TrackingMonth":"",
    "IsApplicable":true
},

{
    "MetricGoalDetailID": 5,
    "MetricID": 2,
    "MetricName": "Cost",
    "MetricGoalID": 1,
    "MetricGoalName": "Sales order enablement (M$)",
    "SubMetricGoalID": 5,
    "SubMetricGoalName": "Running total",
    "MetricValue":09.7,
    "Comments":"Dummy Comments5",
    "TrackingMonth":"",
    "IsApplicable":false
},
{
    "MetricGoalDetailID": 6,
    "MetricID": 2,
    "MetricName": "Cost",
    "MetricGoalID": 1,
    "MetricGoalName": "Revenue Acceleration (M$)",
    "SubMetricGoalID": 6,
    "SubMetricGoalName": "Running total",
    "MetricValue":3.4,
    "Comments":"Dummy Comments6",
    "TrackingMonth":"",
    "IsApplicable":true
}

];
    });


}])
.filter('mapGender', function() {
  var genderHash = {
    1: 'male',
    2: 'female'
  };

  return function(input) {
    var result;
    var match;
    if (!input){
      return '';
    } else if (result = genderHash[input]) {
      return result;
    } else if ( ( match = input.match(/(.+)( \(\d+\))/) ) && ( result = genderHash[match[1]] ) ) {
      return result + match[2];
    } else {
      return input;
    }
  };
});
 app.directive('validNumber', function() {
      return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          if(!ngModelCtrl) {
            return; 
          }

          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
                var val = '';
            }

            var clean = val.replace(/[^-0-9\.]/g, '');
            var negativeCheck = clean.split('-');
            var decimalCheck = clean.split('.');
            if(!angular.isUndefined(negativeCheck[1])) {
                negativeCheck[1] = negativeCheck[1].slice(0, negativeCheck[1].length);
                clean =negativeCheck[0] + '-' + negativeCheck[1];
                if(negativeCheck[0].length > 0) {
                    clean =negativeCheck[0];
                }

            }

            if(!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1])) {
                decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0,2);
                clean =decimalCheck[0] + '.' + decimalCheck[1];
            }

            if (val !== clean) {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
              ngModelCtrl.$render();
            }
            return clean;
          });

          element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode === 32) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

Here is the plnkr link for the same [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SbWcAi?p=preview)

Problem: My directive does not seem to be working.

However the same directive works on a normal text box out side Ui-Grid.

Here is fiddler example of that
[fiddler working link for same directive](http://jsfiddle.net/vfsHX/)